# Rename Table with an ]

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I can't find the right syntax to rename a table in T-SQL when the table name contains an ']' character.

It seems like the sp_rename procedure doesn't use the same escaping rules as T-SQL DDL.

How can this be done?

```
CREATE SCHEMA MySchema

CREATE TABLE [MySchema].[MyTab]]le5](
    [Id] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [SomeField] [bigint] NULL,
    [MyField] [nvarchar](4000) NULL)

EXEC sp_rename 'MySchema.MyTa]ble5', 'MyTable6'
```

Comment: Do you have to use a script? You can rename it in SSMS Ok.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the same syntax as CREATE TABLE...

```
EXEC sp_rename 'MySchema.[MyTab]]le5]', 'MyTable6'
```

Or rely on [SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174393.aspx) ON and a different delimiter

```
EXEC sp_rename 'MySchema."MyTab]le5"', 'MyTable6'
```

Comment: I couldn't get the first one to work. But the second option does - thank you.

Comment: Curiously in the second case you don't need to quote the second parameter, but you do the first.